# How and where can I see <link rel="prerender"> meta tag working?

Tags: html, pre-rendering

How can I check that `<link rel="prerender" href="...">` is actually working? Where in Chrome's DevTools can I see that an `href` URL is loading in the background or something? I see no requests in Network tab related to `href` loading and prerender job.